# Joining partitioned tables in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

Let's say I have two partitioned tables say `customer` and `items` and both are partitioned by `country` and `state` columns.

Is this the right way to join contents of these tables given that I want to retrieve data for a specific country and state?

```
select 
  customer.id, 
  customer.name, 
  items.name, 
  items.value
from
  customers
  join items
  on customers.id == items.customer_id
  and customers.country == 'USA'
  and customers.state == 'TX'
  and items.country == 'USA'
  and items.state == 'TX'
```

or should these conditions go in the WHERE clause?

```
and customers.country == 'USA'
and customers.state == 'TX'
and items.country == 'USA'
and items.state == 'TX'
```

Comment: Those conditions should go in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple queries, Hive will push the predicate before the reduce phase, so in this case the performance will be the same between put the conditions on the "on" or on the "where" clause. But if you write other queries where you are comparing fields between tables (table1.a < table2.b), Hive will perform the join and apply the where condition at the end (reducer phase), like the most of the relational databases.

Answer (score 1):

We can join the partitioned table, partitions are nothing but folder structure, partitions means the way of dividing a table into related parts based on the values of particular columns ex: date , state etc.
For ex, i have partitions like below

```
show partitions table_name1 
year=2016/month=12/day=1/part=10

show partitions table_name2 
year=2016/month=12/day=1/part=1
```

Now we can join table in below ways

```
select i.col1, c.col1
FROM (SELECT * FROM table_name1 WHERE year=2016 AND month=12 AND day=1) i
JOIN (SELECT * FROM table_name2 WHERE year=2016 AND month=12 AND day=1) c
ON i.col2= c.col2
AND i.col3= c.col3
AND i.col3= c.col3
GROUP BY c.col1
```

OR

```
SELECT i.col1, c.col1
FROM table_name1
JOIN table_name2
ON i.col2= c.col2
AND i.col3= c.col3
AND i.col3= c.col3
AND i.year=2016 AND i.month=12 AND i.day=1
AND c.year=2016 AND c.month=12 AND c.day=1
GROUP BY c.col1
```